# Accessing individual elements of an encrypted list in python

Tags: python, encryption

I have a list of strings, and I am using AES encryption to encrypt each of the strings and stores them in a different list.

When I print the entire list, all the encrypted strings can be seen. But when trying to access individual strings, the output is different. What is causing this?

Here is the code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

keywords = ['country', 'state', 'nation', 'area']
i = 0
encryptlist = []

while i < len(keywords):
    obj = AES.new('samplekey1234567',AES.MODE_CFB,'sampleiv12345678')
    encryptlist.append(obj.encrypt(keywords[i]))
    i = i+1

print encryptlist
print encryptlist[0]
```

This is what the output looks like

```
['&\x8cj\xbay\x93\xb9', '65\xfe\xf9s', '+\n\xe1\xa8\xdd~', '$tI\xc7']

&Œjºy“¹
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` on a list invokes `__repr__` on each element, while `print` on a string calls `__str__`

```
>>> '&\x8cj\xbay\x93\xb9'.__str__()
&îj║yô╣

>>> '&\x8cj\xbay\x93\xb9'.__repr__()
'&\x8cj\xbay\x93\xb9'
```

so:

```
>>> print '&\x8cj\xbay\x93\xb9'
&îj║yô╣
```

while

```
>>> print ['&\x8cj\xbay\x93\xb9']
['&\x8cj\xbay\x93\xb9]
```

Comment: Better answer than mine so I took it out :)

Comment: Great answer. I never knew that. I'm still new to python. Thanks, it really helped...